# Is there any way to disable an event pulling data from past uses?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using events to transfer data between classes to all unity `GameObjects` who relate to said event.
I have encountered an issue regarding a part of the code not working properly. On debugging, I found out every time I invoke the event, it pulls data from past invokes as well. Is there any possible solution you have in mind?

[image: Debug.Log of past event's data showing on a new run]

```
void OnAttackable(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActionSO action = new(((GlobalCombatClock.CustomActionEventArg)e).Action);
        bool turnCharacterAllied = GlobalCombatClock.GetTurnCharacter().GetComponent<ObjectCombatManager>().IsAllied;
        bool cardAllied = card.GetComponent<ObjectCombatManager>().IsAllied;
        Debug.Log(GlobalCombatClock.RoundCount + " " + GlobalCombatClock.InitiativeIndex + " " + turnCharacterAllied + cardAllied + action.TargetType.ToString());
        if(action.TargetType switch
        {
            GlobalResources.Targets.singleOpposingTarget => turnCharacterAllied != cardAllied,
            GlobalResources.Targets.singleAlliedTarget => turnCharacterAllied == cardAllied,
            GlobalResources.Targets.multiTarget => turnCharacterAllied != cardAllied,
            GlobalResources.Targets.allies => turnCharacterAllied == cardAllied,
            GlobalResources.Targets.enemies => turnCharacterAllied != cardAllied,
            GlobalResources.Targets.self => card.Equals(GlobalCombatClock.GetTurnCharacter()),
            _ => false
        })
            AttackableVanity(action);
    }
```

This is my code for the function subscribed to the event, because each invoke of this event also hosts the data of all past ones, all cards who were at some point a possible target for an attack become one to all future ones...

Edit 1 - some clarification:

My game uses turn-based combat, therefore my event system works by having multiple subscribers (every combat member is subscribed once per event) to multiple different events to indicate when something happens in the combat, currently this specific event seems to pull data from past invokes for no apparent reason. A single subscriber runs this event for every past turn in combat, each time with the corresponding EventArgs value for that turn.

You can see in the attached picture, on turn 1 3, data was used of an AlliedTarget attack that was used on that turn, MultiTarget attack from the previous turn and an OpposingTarget attack from 2 turns ago, although only the MultiAttack one was used.

Comment: Could you also show the code where you subscribe to the event and invoke the event? The code in OnAttackable does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: `it pulls data from past invokes` what exactly do you mean by that? Also `ActionSO` .. is that a `ScriptableObject`? Why create new clones of it? Looks to me like you're just invoking this multiple time -> you are probably subscribed multiple times

Comment: Cloning the `ActionSO` was just a test to see if the issue was with that `ScriptableObject`, I have since changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future readers:
I solved this issue by looking at my code from a different perspective. Check when and how you fire your events.

In my case, I fired my events by adding listeners to buttons on the UI and I forgot to reset the listeners between turns, giving the results of seemingly having data from past turns resurface, only for it to be one button still having the previous turn's listener...

Only took me 2 days and reworking my whole combat system to find this out...

Answer (score 1):

Irrelevant/outdated subscribers must simply be unsubscribed from events. Then the invocations won't keep triggering for all of them.

If you did not know, subscribing to an event does not remove previous subscribers. Having multiple concurrent subscribers to a single event is exactly one of the reasons this system exists.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify further